# Passando argumentos para .exe de python com cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, cx-freeze

Tenho este código para testar a passagem de argumento

**ola.py**

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print (arg)
print ("Hello World!")
```

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name='Ola',
    version='0.1',             
    description='ola Felipe',  
    executables= [Executable("ola.py")])
```

Porém, quando inicio o programa no Windows, o mesmo não funciona
Tentei passar o programa desta forma, mas não funcionou:

```
>start ola.py teste1 teste2
```

Como devo passar os argumentos para estes executáveis? Ou devo mudar algo no `setup.py` antes de cria-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era só a forma como eu tava chamando :p

Precisa ser:

```
ola.exe teste1 teste2
```